# make "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column cannot be null " into an alert message

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

i want to stop the Integrity constraint violation:

> 1048 Column 'adresse' cannot be null

error message from showing up and turn it into an alert or some error page and make a return to home screen button or smth

i'm a newbie to laravel and phpmyadmin but i had a similar problem with an already exist message.

Comment: Do you control the database tables?  If so, remove the "NOT NULL" contraint on the adresse field in the table.  If you can't, put a bogus value in there so it is happy.  However, there is probably a logic behind the constraint being there in the first place...

Comment: Maybe you should validate that your form inputs are _valid_.

Answer (score 1):

That's because 'addresse' is not nullable. You can update this by either changing the table or editing this line in the existing migration file and refresh the database (tip: you lose all data if you do that)
To change your table without deleting any data and considering the table name is `users`:

`php artisan make:migration updateUsersAddresseFieldTable`

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('adresse')->nullable()->change();
});
```

`php artisan migrate`

If you want to adapt the existing migration file and refresh:

```
$table->string('adresse')->nullable();
```

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: i don't want to change that i just want an exception present to prevent that error from showing ! like and alert message or page

Comment: You can make use of validation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation and show the user error messages. On the other hand, if you have many fields that could be NULL you will be forced to make your code unnecessarily complex. You may want to reiterate which path you will choose. There is a middleware `TrimStrings.php` that forces empty fields to NULL.